# Implementing Queue with unique elements in Redis

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cache

**I need to implement the Queue in Redis with unique elements.**
Currently, I am using the Redis List to implement Queue (LPUSH, RPOP) and Redis Sortedset/set to implement uniqueness.

```
`  
def push(key):
    if redis_cache.zadd('UNIQUE', key, 1):
        redis_cache.lpush('QUEUE', key)
    else:
       print "Key Exist"
`
`
def pop():
    key = redis_cache.rpop('QUEUE')
    redis_cache.zrem('UNIQUE', key)
    return key
`
```

With high load/request of keys the Redis Cache server using more CPU. and also the above approach taking more memory size (The same key is sored in both List and Sortedset)
**Is there any other way to implement the Redis Queue with key uniqueness**?

Answer (score 4):

I'd actually look into using a single Sorted Set, setting the scores as timestamps and using `ZADD`'s "NX" flag. This will provide both ordering and uniqueness.

Comment: Good idea! Although the order is not very accurate (items added in the same second or millisecond are ordered by key), and client might cheat (by specifying a previous timestamp), in most case, it should be a good solution.

Comment: This is the good idea. I think my problem will get solve with this solution. Thank you.

Comment: There are two issues with using timestamps as the `score`: 1) time may go backwards ( due to NTP drift for example). 2) You may get the same timestamp if the `ZADD`s are close to each other - ordering then will be lexicographic which is probably not what you want

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use a `Set`, instead of `Sorted Set` to check if the key already exist. `Sorted Set` uses more memory than `Set`.

Secondly, you code is NOT atomic. If you want to make it atomic, you need to use Lua script or transaction.

> Is there any other way to implement the Redis Queue with key uniqueness?

#### Random Order Queue

If you don't care the order of the queue, i.e. you don't need a FIFO, you can use a single `Set` without a `List` to implement a queue with random out order. This solution will save more memory, and much faster, since it only need to send one command to Redis.

```
// in queue
SADD UNIQUE key

// out queue, pop a random member.
SPOP UNIQUE
```

Comment: Yep, a race condition exists in the pop operation.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25368572/6932198), you must choose between making multiple operations - Cost in time (remove then add again if found during removal) or maintaining a separate set - Cost in memory (your approach).
LREM is O(N), where N is the length of the list, but SREM complexity for one element is O(1) since N is the number of members to be removed. And SISMEMBER is always O(1).